OTel Probabilistic Sampler passes zero logs
I ran into an issue and have tried to simplify my config as much as possible, but cannot get any logs to pass through the OTel Probabilistic Sampling Processor.
Even when testing locally with a minimal config (posted below), no logs ever pass through.
I have tested and everything works as expected for traces and I see logs from the debug exporter when the probabilistic_sampler is not in the pipeline (for logs). However, when I add it into the log processors block, no logs pass. I understand that the default processor settings won't work since logs don't have traceID, but I have tried setting the attribute to use and I have tried setting sampling_percentage to 100. Even with that setting, no logs pass through.
Simplified testing config.yaml
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4317

processors:
  probabilistic_sampler:
# Tested with many different values set here
#    hash_seed: 22
    sampling_percentage: 100
#    attribute_source: record
#    from_attribute: "Timestamp"

exporters:
  debug:
    verbosity: detailed

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [probabilistic_sampler]
      exporters: [debug]
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [probabilistic_sampler]
      exporters: [debug]

Simple testing script to run the otel docker image. I have tried "latest", "0.103.1", and "0.102.1".
#!/bin/zsh

CONFIG_PATH=./config.yaml

if [[ ! -f $CONFIG_PATH ]];then
  echo No file found at $CONFIG_PATH
fi

docker run \
  -v $CONFIG_PATH:/etc/otelcol-contrib/config.yaml \
  -p 127.0.0.1:4317:4317 \
  -p 127.0.0.1:55679:55679 \
  otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:latest \
  2>&1 | tee collector-output.txt

Running this works as expected (logs show up in stdout from the otel process) when there are no processors in the logs pipeline.
telemetrygen logs --otlp-insecure --logs 10

Similarly, running it with traces works as expected with and without the processor.
I know that this processor is only in alpha for logs, but I see plenty of posts around where other people have much more complex systems working fine. I think I've been staring at the docs too long to see what is wrong here.
